# Hyperlink Cell based on Value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I Have trawled the forums looking for a solution.

I have a code for creating a hyperlink based on the column B cell value. It works but only if the I run the sub whilst selecting the cell.

What I need is for the hyperlink to get automatically added if the cell in column H's value is "ok"

```
Sub Hyperlinks()

Dim r As Range
Dim FilePath As String

If Intersect(Columns("B"), Selection) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each r In Intersect(Selection, Range("B2:B" & _
Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))
If r <> vbNullString Then

FilePath = "T:\BLUEMAC\Search Paths\PDF MASTER FOLDER\"

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, _
Address:=FilePath & r.Value & ".pdf", TextToDisplay:=r.Value
End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
If Intersect(Columns("B"), Selection) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each r In Intersect(Selection, Range("B2:B" & _
Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))
```

To

```
For Each r In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
```

And

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, _
Address:=FilePath & r.Value & ".pdf", TextToDisplay:=r.Value
```

To

```
If r.offset(0,6).value = "ok" then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, _
Address:=FilePath & r.Value & ".pdf", TextToDisplay:=r.Value
```

Comment: @JamesHurst Don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped (the tick on the left hand side)

Comment: Jochen you have been a tremendous help, Can you maybe have a look at another problem im having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219465/join-cells-based-on-value-of-a-cell-vba

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Sub Hyperlinks()

Dim r As Range
Dim FilePath As String

If Intersect(Columns("B"), Selection) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each r In Intersect(Selection, Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))
    If r <> vbNullString And LCase$(r.Offset(0, 6).value) = "ok" Then
        FilePath = "T:\BLUEMAC\Search Paths\PDF MASTER FOLDER\"
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, _
             Address:=FilePath & r.Value & ".pdf", TextToDisplay:=r.Value
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I think James needs code that does not depend on `Selection`

Comment: That is working, but it is still only working if the cell is selected and the sub run. how can i get it to go through every cell in column B automatically

Comment: Yes that looks like the issue, Ill need to replace the intersect part with something else, but what?

Comment: Jochen has the answer

Comment: Went out for lunch sorry - yes looks like Jochen has it

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways guys, this site has been awesome